# Выбрать из списка ключевых слов соответствующее введенному

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Вообщем передо мной стоит такая задача:
есть поле, в которое пользователь вводит какое-то ключевое слово.
И есть список с ключевыми словами, когда пользователь вводит слово, в списке остаются только те слова, которые соответствуют вводимому слову.
Сама соль состоит в том что сам список должен быть виден сразу в отдельном `<div>` и когда начинается ввод ключевого слова в `<div>` кол-во слов уменьшается и остаются только соответствующие.

У меня грубо говоря есть массив с ключевыми словами на пример:

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++", ... и т.д.
```

вот есть функция 
`$("#region").autocomplete({source: availableTags});` - которая выводит список ключевых слов, но она его выводит только когда начинается заполнение поля. И выводит в виде списка для поля, а надо в отдельном `<div>` всё выводилось... 
Как мне это сделать. Спасибо?

Comment: Вот пример что нужно реализовать, только по проще:
http://tiu.ru/
Под логотипом надпись "Вся Россия"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Сама соль состоит в том что сам список должен быть виден сразу в отдельном <div>

- ну, и выводите сразу весь список.
- когда пользователь начинает набирать, то выводите соответствующие теги.
- проверяете - если поле пустое, то опять вывести все теги в блок

Comment: когда пользователь начинает набирать, то выводите соответствующие теги.
а можно с этого места по подробнее?

Comment: @dieselwolf, что ж тут можно подробнее описать? Сравниваете набираемые сочетания символов со словами/фразами в вашем массиве и те, что попадают под фильтр - выводите вместо всех тех, что выведены на данный момент.P.S. Кстати, в инете можно найти достаточно готовых решений. Вот, например, [такой вариант](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-tables/full_screen_preview/53366), ([more info](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-tables/53366))

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогло.